# ElevatedButton, TextButton and OutlinedButton gradient

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Before it was easy to make a gradient button with the default ButtonThemeData... But now I can't figure out how to properly make a custom gradient button using the new MaterialButtons.

I am trying to make a three custom gradient button which must use the ButtonStyle defined in the AppTheme (splashColor, elevation, ...).

#### ElevatedButton

GradientElevatedButton that uses the ElevatedButtonThemeData with a gradient background

#### TextButton

GradientTextButton that uses the TextButtonThemeData with a gradient text

#### OutlinedButton

GradientOutlinedButton that uses the OutlinedButtonThemeData with a gradient border and a gradient text

### Already tried

I have tried to wrap an ElevatedButton with a ShaderMask but it covers the ink animations so it doesn't accomplish my goals.

Comment: Would like to know as well

Comment: Good question. Instead of making it simpler and more intuitive they made it worse than it was. We should be able to figure these things with the autocomplete feature. Now, this question has over 20 days on SO with no answer.

Answer (score 3):

- #### `ElevatedButton`

  [image]

  ```dart
  DecoratedBox(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue])),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.transparent),
      child: Text('Elevated Button'),
    ),
  )
  ```

---

- #### `OutlinedButton`

  [image]

  For `OutlinedButton`, you need to do some extra steps. Create a class (null-safe):

  ```dart
  class MyOutlinedButton extends StatelessWidget {
    final VoidCallback onPressed;
    final Widget child;
    final ButtonStyle? style;
    final Gradient? gradient;
    final double thickness;

    const MyOutlinedButton({
      Key? key,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.child,
      this.style,
      this.gradient,
      this.thickness = 2,
    }) : super(key: key);

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: gradient),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(thickness),
          child: OutlinedButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            style: style,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  ```

  Usage:

  ```dart
  MyOutlinedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.indigo, Colors.pink]),
    child: Text('OutlinedButton'),
  )
  ```

Comment: Don't forger to add `shadowColor: Colors.transparent` into ElevatedButton style to make colors OK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but I just did it by myself this way. Still don't get why they have to make things more complicated.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/src/utils/style_helper.dart';
import 'package:my_app/src/utils/themes.dart';

class SecondaryButtonState extends State<SecondaryButton> {

  setPressed(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      widget.pressed = value;
    });
  }

  getDecoration() {
    if (widget.disabled) {
      return BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(SH.BORDER_RADIUS),
        color: ThemeColors.secondaryLight,
      );
    }
    if (!widget.pressed) {
      return BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
            end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
            colors: [ThemeColors.gradient, ThemeColors.secondary]),
      );
    } else {
      return BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(SH.BORDER_RADIUS),
          color: ThemeColors.secondary);
    }
  }

  void onTapDown(TapDownDetails details) {
    if (!widget.disabled) {
      setPressed(true);
    }
  }

  void onTapUp(TapUpDetails details) {
    if (!widget.disabled) {
      setPressed(false);
      widget.onPressed();
    }
  }

  TextStyle getTextStyle(context, Set<MaterialState> states) {
    return Theme.of(context)
        .textButtonTheme
        .style
        .textStyle
        .resolve(states)
        .copyWith();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTapDown: onTapDown,
      onTapUp: onTapUp,
      child: Container(
          width: 400,
          decoration: getDecoration(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SH.PC, horizontal: SH.P3),
          child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                widget.icon != null ? widget.icon : Container(),
                Text(
                  widget.label,
                  style: Theme.of(context)
                      .elevatedButtonTheme
                      .style
                      .textStyle
                      .resolve(null)
                      .copyWith(),
                ),
              ])),
    );
  }
}

class SecondaryButton extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondaryButton(
      {@required this.onPressed,
      @required this.label,
      this.icon,
      this.disabled = false});

  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;
  final String label;
  bool disabled;
  final Icon icon;
  bool pressed = false;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SecondaryButtonState();
  }
}
```