# Flutter - how can i define GradientColor inside ElevatedButtonThemeData

Tags: flutter, themes, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm currently on the step of defining my app theme, i'm trying to define `LinearGradient` color for `ElevatedButton` is there a way to define it on `ElevatedButtonThemeData`, all the solutions i've found point to wrap the `ElevatedButton` widget with container and define the `gradient` color on the container, but that's undoable when defining the theme for `ElevatedButton`

Comment: Can you include what you;ve tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying

Please check the below question, it might help you.

[ElevatedButton, TextButton and OutlinedButton gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355441/elevatedbutton-textbutton-and-outlinedbutton-gradient)